# How to Create a new database in java eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, database, create-table, datecreated

I'm currently learning Java and I want to create a database named `Login` that has two columns: one is named `Username` and the other is named `Password`.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class sqlCreateDataBase {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/;create = true", "root", null);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String databaseName = "Login";

            String sql = "CREATE DATABASE " + databaseName;
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            System.out.println("Creating the Login table...");
            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE login("  +
                "Username CHAR(25), " +
                "Password CHAR(10)");

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

            System.out.println("Done");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.print("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please let us know concretely what's your question? It would also be good to mention what are the errors you're getting.

Comment: You say you want to create database, I can see you tries to create table.

Comment: @Gerson areche I believe you want to create tables and not database. Could you please provide detailed info about what your question is?

Comment: I want to create a new database. I copy the example from a java book but I keep getting error

Comment: Error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/;create = true.

Comment: Basically create everything from scratch through java eclipse and not from phpmyadmin is what I want to do.